# Order of cards drawn from various sources wrt overdraw?

Tags: monster-train

In Monster Train, you discard your remaining non-frozen cards at the end of each turn.
After the combat phase, a new turn starts, wherein you draw 5 more cards from the draw pile.

There are other sources of card draws though. Specifically, all sources are:

- Enemies putting status effects into your hand.
- Artifacts that generate a card at the start of your turn
- Creature effects that generate cards via Resolve. *Example: Flicker's 'copy a random defeated card' leader ability.*
- 5 natural draws. *optionally twice upgradeable to 6, then 7*

There is a maximum hand size, *by default this is 10 cards*. I want clarification on the following scenario: When the amount of cards added to the hand at the start of turn exceeds 10, some of these sources do not produce cards: some draws are skipped. So it's sometimes important to know the order in which these are considered so you know which sources are lost first.

In addition to that, it's not clear to me what happens when some of the 'overdraw' is generated material. Where does it go? To the void, to the discard pile, on top of the deck? Or does this depend on the 'type' of card it is?

---

Motivation: Lost a run when a deck dependent on Imp-cicle increased its start-of-turn draws so that it had more than 10 cards in hand, preventing it from generating enough Imps to power up Transcendimp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my gameplay experience, it seems to be as follows:

Resolve triggers would be first,
As they are not actually at the start of your turn, rather at the end of the previous turn.
[Here is a short clip](https://youtu.be/IsL3NDRLh1o) I made showing that the [Rector Flicker's Dark Calling](https://monster-train.fandom.com/wiki/Rector_Flicker) upgrade activates before I have drawn any cards.

Now for start of turn effects:

1. Cards are added to your hand from a Boss,
   such as [The Ultimate Penance](https://monster-train.fandom.com/wiki/The_Ultimate_Penance) from the second major boss, [Fel](https://monster-train.fandom.com/wiki/Fel,_the_Wings_of_Light).
2. You then draw cards equal to your Draw Power, indicated with a small number beside your deck, in the bottom left corner. [In this example, 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTqvB.jpg). This can be increased from the [Herzal's Compound](https://monster-train.fandom.com/wiki/Artifacts#Boss) artifact, and other various sources such as [Sting](https://monster-train.fandom.com/wiki/Sting).
3. Additional cards are added to your hand from cards that state "**at the start of your turn**". [Here is another video example.](https://youtu.be/N99QxwDQTp4)

As you noted, if there are too many cards in your hand (maximum is always 10) when the "start of turn" artifacts trigger, they simply won't do anything.

Other enemies such as [Absolver](https://monster-train.fandom.com/wiki/Absolver) or [Purifier](https://monster-train.fandom.com/wiki/Purifier) that put Scourge cards into your deck do not add them to your hand, they add them to the top of your deck, so when you draw them it looks like they are first but that is only because they were added to the top of your deck, they were not put into your hand. This is really worse as it means you are drawing fewer cards as well.